# Pasar variable de una pagina a otra

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

- En `pagina1.php` la persona ingresa su numero de documento,
- en `pagina2.php` hacemos una consulta, un envió de mail y te direcciona a pagina3.php,
- en `pagina3.php` tenemos dos opciones, una comunicarse por wtsp y la otra por correo electrónico que es la que nos importa ahora,
- esta última se ejecuta `en pagina4.php` que también te envía un correo electrónico

Por ende, necesitariamos el número de documento que usamos en `pagina1.php` para hacer la *query* en `pagina4.php`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo utilizando variables de sesion.

En primer lugar debes inicializar la sesion poniendo **al principio del todo** en tu código PHP:

> session_start();

Una vez hayas inicializado la sesión, debes asignar el valor que quieres a una determinada variable de sesión, así:

> $_SESSION['tu_variable'] = 'valor_asignado';

Con esto, la variable de sesión "tu_variable" mantendrá dicho valor "al moverte" a otras páginas, pero es necesario que inicies la sesión en cada una de estas páginas donde vayas a hacer uso de ella(s).

Si no te he entendido mal, el página1.php el usuario ingresa un valor que recoges en pagina2.php y necesitas ese valor en pagina4.php

En ese caso, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

PAGINA2.PHP (recoges el valor y lo asignas a una variable de sesion):

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['tu_variable'] = 'valor_asignado';
```

PAGINA4.PHP (recuperas el valor de tu variable de sesión):

```
<?php
session_start();
$variable = $_SESSION['tu_variable'];
```

No es necesario que inicies la sesion en pagina3.php, ya que, a no ser que destruyas la sesion (con session_destroy()), tu sesión se mantendrá activa. No obstante, si necesitases recuperar el valor en pagina3.php, también podrías obtenerla de la misma forma que haces en pagina4.php (iniciando la sesión y accediendo a ella a través de $_SESSION)

Echale también un vistazo a la documentación oficial de [3WC](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) y de [PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/session.examples.basic.php). Es muy sencillo de entender y son realmente útiles.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola @cooper fijate que modifique la pregunta porque me exprese mal, eso que me pasas a explicar ya lo hago en mis otras paginas

Comment: @ElioFarac no te preocupes. Es normal. Ahí tienes la modificación.

Comment: me funciono y te explicaste muy bien! muchisimas gracias!